# wp_insert_user wont return the ID of the user

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a sort of a marketplace website where users add a product then register. The user gets added and product gets added but I cant get the user ID to attach to the product after using wp_insert_user. Here is what I have.

in my page-list.php

```
   if(isset($_POST['user_signup']) == '1') {

    $user_login = $_POST['email_seller'];
    $pas1 = $_POST['pass_seller'];
    $user_email = $_POST['email_seller'];
    $seller_name = $_POST['name_seller'];
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login'  =>  $user_login,
        'user_email' =>  $user_email,
        'user_pass'   =>  $pas1,
        'role' => 'seller', 
         'first_name' => $user_email,
            'last_name' => $user_email,

    );
  $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
```

and the code I have in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'create_new_user_posts', 10, 1 );

function create_new_user_posts($user_id){
        if (!$user_id>0)
                return;



                $post_title = $_POST['post_title'];
                $post_cat = $_POST['cat'];
                $term_id = get_term( $post_cat, 'product_cat' );
                $post_category = $term_id->slug; 
                $post_cat_two = $_POST['cat_two'];


                $new_post = array(
                      'ID' => '',
                      'post_author' => $user_id, 
                      'post_content' => $post_content, 
                      'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags($post_title),
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
                      'post_type' => 'product',
                      'post_excerpt'=> $post_excerpt
                    );

                $post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);

                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $user_id, 'soldby', false );



}
```

Comment: What is the content of `$user_id` ?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte idk thats kinda the issue I how do i test that print_r()? because when I do that nothing gets returned

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead

Comment: @FelippeDuarte that returned  int(589)

Comment: That is the user id. What's wrong?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte  wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $user_id, 'soldby', false );
    Will not set to the users ID